# JavaScript loop through a JSON.stringify(data)

Tags: javascript, json

I want to Loop through my data and do stuff.

Following

```
var stuff = JSON.stringify(data)
```

Returns me something like this:

```
{"0":"data:image/png;base64,testi,"2":"data:image/png;base64, testi2, ....
```

I Need to Loop through that but the Approach I did, did not work.

```
        for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++) {
            $('#img-thumb-id'+i).attr('src', data[i]);
        }
```

**Edit**

I am using `JSON.stringify`  because `console.log(data)` just returned me object object which I cant work with.

Comment: `data` is an object.. you should use `for (var key in data) { ... }`

Comment: The only thing that the output from `JSON.stringify` should ever be passed to is a JSON decoder.  Why are you taking a perfectly good data structure and then trying to parse its serialised form?

Comment: I am using JSON.stringify  because if I console.log data I just get Object Object

Comment: @Olipol — Converting an object to a string of JSON it not remotely like converting it to an array.

Comment: @Olipol If you want the string representation of your object to display in debugging, then sure, `stringify` will do that, but if you want a useful data structure with properties, don't turn it into a string (or at least don't assume it will still be a useful data structure after you turn it into a string).

Comment: Try Changing this `$('#img-thumb-id'+i).attr('src', data[i]);` to `$('#img-thumb-id'+i).attr('src', data[i.toString()]);`

Comment: @Olipol fine, but you don't want to use that same string output for actually working on the data

Comment: I dunno `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ... `did not work
`

Comment: Related: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to loop through `data`, then you need to loop through **`data`**.

Converting it to a JSON document will give you a string. You can't (usefully) loop through that.

Since converting it to JSON shows that it is an object, not an array, it is unlikely to have a `length`, so you'll need to [use a method to loop over objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object).

Comment: hi thanks how would the Loop look like, just a Basic Loop through that data, earlier I tried to Loop through data.length but that did not work aswell

Comment: @Olipol — See the last paragraph of this answer (including a link to a whole question about that).

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop over object keys you can use:

```
var keys = Object.keys(data);
```

Which gives you an array with all the keys in your object.
Now you can loop the values by:

```
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
   var value = data[key];
   // your code here...
}
```